# Which input element that accept digits only and allows a limited number of characters

Tags: html

I am trying to implement an (`zip code` of my country) input field that only accept digits and limit the number of characters to 5.

Which html input type and attributes are more appropriate for this task ?

Comment: html5 input type text accept patern with regular expression.

Comment: Using html5 input type text accept pattern with regular expression prevent me from submitting the form because the input is not valid. but It still allows me to enter any number of characters.

Comment: What I want is the behavior that we can have by using input type text with maxlength attribute. but that allows only digits.

Comment: there is no more in HTML5 ( except validation services), you have to intercept input keys value a make a js code for

Comment: @MisterJojo I don't care about other zip codes. forget that it's a zip code. I want an input fields that accept only digits with a fixed length of characters.

Comment: I care about the Zip format, in my country it's a mix of letters and numbers. You have not explained the type of zip code you are looking for. Also, the only solution for you is to use javascript code, as I write here before.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="zipcode" pattern="[0-9]{5}" />
```

`pattern="\d{5}"` would also work. But make sure to re-check it in your target-script because form-elements can be manipulated.

Comment: This doesn't work!, I am able to enter alphanumeric characters with any length. https://jsbin.com/hegizemebu/edit?html,output

Comment: Yes you can enter everything but you can't SEND the form itself if this is not numeric!

Comment: To check the input imediatly you need to listen ´onkeyup` or `onchange` to the field(s), check the values and output an error to the user. Also you have to `preventDefault` action on submit. Do you want an code example?

Answer (score 0):

A complete example (**WITH JQUERY**) for checking values on `change` or `keyup` in the `.checkFieldNum` values and on submit the form.

JS

```
    function checkNum(value)
    {
      return value.match(/\d{5}/);
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //  trigger if element-value with class="checkFieldNum" changes or key is pressed
      $('.checkFieldNum').on('change keyup',function(event){
        if(checkNum($(this).val()) === false)
        {
            $(this).css({background:'tomato'})
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).css({background:''})
        }
      })
        //  trigger if form should be submitted
      $('.formClassForSubmit').on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var goOn = true;
        $('.checkFieldNum').each(function(){
          if(checkNum($(this).val()) === false)
          {
            goOn = false;
            alert($(this).attr('name') + ' has wrong value')
          }
        })
        if(goOn === true)
        {
          // In this case, everything is OK and go on whatever you will do..
        }
      })
    })
```

HTML

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form action="?" method="post" class="formClassForSubmit">
      <input type="text" class="checkFieldNum" name="zipcode1" pattern="[0-9]{5}" />
      <input type="text" class="checkFieldNum" name="zipcode2" pattern="\d{5}" />
      <input type="submit" name="send" value="send" />
    </form>
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/7hbj6a3e/3/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I know I can do it with javascript, the question is about whether there is a built in html element that can do it.

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="number" minlength="5" maxlength="5" name="zipcode" />
```

see https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Comment: Zip codes are not numeric input. You would not increment or decrement a zip code, and they are many circumstances where they contain non-numeric characters, such as the 5+4 format, or when you need to support multiple countries.

Comment: than use `type="text"`

Comment: the question was "Which input element that accept digits *only*"

Comment: For this one, Although I am able to fill only digits, I can enter any number of characters.

Comment: @zzzzBov I don't care about other zip codes. forget that it's a zip code. I look for an input field that accept only digits with a fixed length of characters

Comment: @zzzzBov well, in my case it's numeric due the fact that it only contains digits. I don't need to increment or decrement.

Comment: the only downpoint is zero's at the start of the value. A value like '01234' would be int '1234' at the end, so you have to take care if you output the value use e.g. `str_pad($value,5,0,STR_PAD_LEFT)`